# dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary within a dictionary but the dictionaries always end up with the same details.

Here's the code:

```
Class DailyStatement(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.masterdict={}
     self.subdict={}
     self.list_of_subdicts=['yesterday','today'] 
     self.keys=['high','low','open','close']
     self._create_masterdict()

  def _create_masterdict(self):
     for subdict in self.list_of_subdicts:
       self.masterdict[subdict]={}
       self.masterdict[subdict]=self.create_subdict(subdict)
       print self.masterdict[subdict]

  def create_subdict(self,subdict):
     for item in self.keys:
       subdict[item]=self.get_value(item,subdict)
     return self.subdict

  def get_value(self,item,subdict):
     {code to find the value}
     return value
```

when I run:

```
ds=DailyStatement()
```

it prints fine and seems to be working perfectly, showing on the console:

```
 {'high':2,'low':1,'open':1.5,'close':1.6}
 {'high':2.2,'low':2.1,'open':2.5,'close':2.6}
```

but when I run:

```
print ds.masterdict
```

I get:

```
{'today':{'high':2,'low':1,'open':1.5,'close':1.6},
 'yesterday':{'high':2,'low':1,'open':1.5,'close':1.6}}
```

I can't understand why this is. It seems to build the masterdict fine when initiating the `Class`, but after the code runs is the `dictionary` rewriting itself?

I have been looking at this problem for the past few hours and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please take more care posting your code. You have a typo in the name of your `__init__` method, and you have missed the `self` in the call to `_create_masterdict`.

Comment: Also, where do all those dicts come from? yesterday,today, high, low, open, and close are not defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry about that. I have corrected these mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `self.subdict` for both of the sub dictionaries. What you should be doing is creating a new sub dictionary every time you need one:

```
import random

class DailyStatement(object):  # changed from C to c
  def __init__(self):  # Added self
     self.masterdict={}
     # Removed self.subdict
     self.list_of_subdicts=['yesterday', 'today'] 
     self.keys=['high', 'low', 'open', 'close']
     self._create_masterdict()

  def _create_masterdict(self):
     for subdict in self.list_of_subdicts:
       self.masterdict[subdict] = {}
       self.masterdict[subdict] = self.create_subdict(subdict)  # added self
       print self.masterdict[subdict]

  def create_subdict(self, subdict):
     sub_dict = {}
     for item in self.keys:
        sub_dict[item] = self.get_value(item, subdict)  # added self
     return sub_dict  

  def get_value(self, item, subdict):  # added self
     return random.randrange(1,4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ds=DailyStatement()
  print ds.masterdict
```

I've left comments on the other changes.

Here is a simple example in the python repl:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> y = {}
>>> x = y
>>> y["NOEL"] = "ROCKS"
>>> x
{'NOEL': 'ROCKS'}
>>>
```

As you can observe x has never been directly set but still contains the key and value that were added to y.